# VSCode keeps opening powershell on start even though Git Bash is set as default

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have set my integrated default terminal in VSCode as Git Bash but whenever I launch VSCode, powershell pops up instead of bash. It does not, however, change the default terminal setting but it is irritating.
I have tried removing the profile of powershell from settings but that seems to do nothing.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": null,
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Windows PowerShell": null
    },
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "Git Bash",
    "powershell.enableProfileLoading": false,
    "powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": false
}
```

Comment: Where do you then set path to Git Bash (`"path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`)?

Comment: The vscode will detect the install of shell defined in ```"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" ```, if not you can directly add the source directly as the value of source. Refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you upgrade to vscode v1.60.1 - there is a fix in that point release for this issue.

---

See [Select Default Profile do not actually open gitbash. After relaunch, on startup, it just keeps open PowerShell](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123684).

The same thing was happening to me and the referred to fix in the Insiders' Build 05/14/2021 did in fact fix it for me.  In the meantime, opening another terminal does always open git bash for me - but that is a pain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Recent update 1.56.2 does not seem to have fixed this issue. I hope they fix this soon.
I, tried setting automationShell of windows to Git Bash and this seems to work.
Can you share how you fixed it?

Comment: I meant it fixed it in the Insiders Build - which I use for some projects.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently on v1.60.1 but still have same issue.

Comment: i'm using 1.64.2 and the issue is still happening

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround without using the Insider's Build that may work for some of you : I removed all profiles safe for the one I want, and reinstalled VS Code. Then it somehow started using the right terminal on startup. I don't know if this works without disabling all other profiles though.

Answer (score 1):

I was still having this issue, and what worked for me was:

1. When PowerShell opened, I reset GitBash to my default, and then killed the terminal (so there were no terminal's running).
2. Removed the terminal panel from view by clicking the X in the top right
3. Closed VSCode
4. When I opened my codebase again and showed the terminal, it began working.

Comment: It seems to be a very bad bug.  I have tried what you mentioned and it works for awhile and then goes back to Powershell eventually.

Comment: So far my above fix hasn't stopped working yet, but I will keep the answer updated if it does. I agree with you, a very bad bug is a good summary.

Comment: Still seeing this in 1.60 but I never had an problem prior to this version. Have removed all profiles except `Git Bash`, still powershell appears on opening VSCode if I leave the terminal panel open when closing.

Comment: Same for me, I can't prevent it from launching Powershell first no matter what I do.

Comment: Since 1.60 for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150) that is still not fixed in the current version (1.60.0).

---

This is now fixed in my current version (1.61.1).

Answer (score 1):

Just did an update to version 1.60.1
and it fixed it.

From the release notes the [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150) was addressed and has since been merged.

Update 1.60.1: The update addresses these [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22August+2021+Recovery%22+is%3Aclosed)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29841729)

Comment: @LexLustor Please explain how to elaborate on "I updated to version 1.60.1 and that fixed it".

Comment: @Scratte I was refering to the fact that the content of the link could be summarized in MrKudu answer, pointing that a PR adressing the bug as been merged in the version 1.60.1 of VS Code, effectively solving the problem (not just 'seems'). Thanks for pointing my original comment : your comment makes mine a rather "pedantic" one.

Comment: @LexLustor will keep that in mind for next time.