# Is there any way to permanently set the default shell to Command Prompt in Visual Sudio Code 1.56.2?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am able to set the default terminal profile to cmd when the editor is open, but when I restart Visual Studio Code the default profile gets set to powershell again.

Comment: How are you setting it currently?

Comment: See duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/67552897/836330 It is a known issue fixed in the Insiders already.